# Explicit vs implicit type definition in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, types

I'm just beginning to learn TensorFlow. Quoting from the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/low_level_intro#graph):

> Let's build a simple computational graph. The most basic operation is a constant. The Python function that builds the operation takes a tensor value as input. The resulting operation takes no inputs. When run, it outputs the value that was passed to the constructor. We can create two floating point constants a and b as follows:

```
a = tf.constant(3.0, dtype=tf.float32)
b = tf.constant(4.0) # also tf.float32 implicitly
total = a + b
print(a)
print(b)
print(total)
```

The second constant is implicitly typed as a float32. Is that based on the explicit typing of the first constant? And does that imply that the first `dtype` is required? [tf.constant documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/constant) would imply that it does not:

> If the argument dtype is not specified, then the type is inferred from the type of `value`.

But then it would be unnecessary to explicitly type the 3.0 constant above.

I'm just looking for some clarification on this, since, like I said, I'm just starting out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But then it would be unnecessary to explicitly type the 3.0 constant
>   above.

Absolutely correct.

```
a = tf.constant(3.0, dtype=tf.float32)
```

is equivalent to:

```
a = tf.constant(3.0)
```

The documentation is just demonstrating the different overloads. We might choose to explicitly provide the type if we want a different numerical precision (or even just to aid human readability) but if you want the default data type TF infers, then it's entirely unnecessary.